# Entity replacement

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to replace entity for below xml,

```
<para>&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;2015033555</para>
<para>New York • Stuttgart • Delhi • Rio de Janeiro</para>
```

Output should be

```
<para>&#x00A0;&#x00A0;&#x00A0;&#x00A0;&#x00A0;&#x00A0;&#x00A0;2015033555</para>        
<para>New York &#x2022; Stuttgart &#x2022; Delhi &#x2022; Rio de Janeiro</para>
```

XSLT is like as,

```
<xsl:template match="//text()">

    <xsl:copy-of select="replace(.,'&#160;','&#x00A0;')"/>
  <xsl:copy-of select="replace(.,'•','&#x2022;')"/>        
</xsl:template>
```

Using above mentioned xslt, it's not giving proper output. Can you help use to replace entity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a character map (https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#character-maps):

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:output use-character-maps="m1"/>

    <xsl:character-map name="m1">
        <xsl:output-character character="&#160;" string="&amp;#x00A0;"/>
        <xsl:output-character character="•" string="&amp;#x2022;"/>        
    </xsl:character-map>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Online sample at http://xsltransform.net/pNmBy22.

Keep in mind that the XSLT processor does not know whether the input had a character literally or as a numeric character reference or as a hexidecimal character reference or as some named entity reference as it uses an underlying XML parser to parse the lexical input XML into the XSLT/XPath tree model which simply has nodes with value as Unicode character sequences. So the character map approach above will output any non-breaking space the XSLT outputs as the sequence `&#x00A0;` and any dot as `&#x2022;`, independent of the original input markup.

Comment: Thanku for your response Martin. It's working properly.